# Response.Redirect("~/landing/index.aspx?", false) Session IDs are changing

Tags: asp.net

On my login.aspx page, i'm simply doing `Session.Add("userID", userID);` and then `Response.Redirect("landing/index.aspx?UID=" + Session["userID"],false);`

When I hit index.aspx all my session keys are gone.

Anybody have any ideas?  This happens in VS2010

This also happens when I publish to IIS.

It was working, and no i didnt change the code.

---

Edit, okay so I placed a few `string sessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID.ToString();` and it seems i'm getting a new SessionId, any thoughts on why this is happening?

-- EDIT

So I added `<sessionState cookieless="true"></sessionState>` to the web.config and now the session ID doesnt change.   However, It still loosing all my Sessioninfo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to store the data in `Session` like following

```
Session["userID"] = userID;
```